# How to disable evolutions in play

Tags: playframework, playframework-evolutions

I don't use evolutions and I want to disable it.
I have used `play.evolutions.enabled=false`and its working, the evolution table is not created, i don't get messages BUT I still have the evolution folder created every time, when I run the server it create evoltuon.default folder with 1.sql file in it.
It's not running the file but I want to disable the creation of this folder.
Any suggestions?

Comment: can you post your `build.sbt` file?

Comment: have you removed the dependency? which version of play are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to disable Play Evolutions (in version 2.7.3) - by adding following configuration (e.g. *application.conf*):

```
play.modules.disable += "play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsModule"
```